# process data with header in rows in python csv

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, pandas

I have a csv file that has the product name in the first row and data headers in second row and from third row onwards contains the actual data with status of each user.

And the csv file looks like this:

```
adidas,,
USER_ID,USER_NAME
b012345,zaihan,Process
b212345,nurhanani,Check
b843432,nasirah,Call
b712345,ibrahim,Check
nike,,
USER_ID,USER_NAME
b842134,khalee,Call
h123455,shabree,Process
b777345,ibrahim,Process
b012345,zaihan,Check
b843432,nasirah,Call
b312451,nurhanani,Process
```

I would like to split the data product wise and rearrange the header and data like this:

> **From header like this**
>
> ```
>    adidas,,
>    USER_ID,USER_NAME
>    b012345,zaihan,Process
> ```
>
> **To header like this**
>
> ```
>   USER_ID,USER_NAME,adidas
>   b012345,zaihan,Process
> ```

And create [`DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) of each product and [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) them like this:

[image]

I had been writing the code for sometime and I think I've to hard-code the headers (for example, 'adidas' and 'nike') since what I understand from reading SO answers is, I need unique header names and the following code is not getting what I want:

My python code is:

```
import csvkit
import sys
import os
from csvkit import convert

with open('/tmp/csvdata.csv', 'rb') as q:
    reader = csvkit.reader(q)
    with open('/tmp/csvdata2.csv', 'wb') as s:
        data = csvkit.writer(s)
        data.writerow(['Name', 'Userid', 'adidas', 'nike'])
        for row in reader:
            row_data = [row[0], row[1], row[2], '']
            data = csvkit.writer(s)
            data.writerow(row_data)
```

**EDIT**

So I got a solution from @piRSquared, which is correct if there are unique set of records for a product, but there could be multiple status for each user for the same product. And the solution gives `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`

An example for the input CSV data that having multiple status and will cause this problem:

```
adidas,,
USER_ID,USER_NAME
b012345,zaihan,Process
h003455,shabree,Check
b212345,nurhanani,Check
b843432,nasirah,Call
b712345,ibrahim,Check
b712345,ibrahim,Process
nike,,
USER_ID,USER_NAME
b842134,khalee,Call
h123455,shabree,Process
b777345,ibrahim,Process
b012345,zaihan,Check
b843432,nasirah,Call
b312451,nurhanani,Process
```

I hope to achieve a result like this, seemingly that users in the same brand category can have the same id,name and both Process and Check.

```
USER_ID,USER_NAME,adidas,nike
b012345,zaihan,Process
h003455,shabree,Check,Process
b212345,nurhanani,Check,Process
b843432,nasirah,Call,Call
b712345,ibrahim,Check
b712345,ibrahim,Process 
b777345,ibrahim,,Process
b842134,khalee,,Call
```

The end result should have an additional row like the above for users which has ***both Check and Process*** in the same brands (in this case the ***user ibrahim in nike brand***)

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Also do you really have USERNAME  and USER_NAME?

Comment: So sorry, it is suppose to be USER_NAME

Comment: can we always consider the headers to be upper case?

Comment: Yes, i think i can write another python script to make 'adidas' and 'nike' as uppercase  which is a hardcode that finds it and replaces.

Comment: Where does Check come from in `b12345,zaihan,Process,Check,`? I really don't understand where you are getting your expected output from

Comment: The `Process, Check` is based on `adidas, nike` column and `b12345, zaihan` is based on `USER_ID and USER_NAME` columns respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this is complicated.

## Solution

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import re
import pandas as pd

text = """adidas,,
USER_ID,USER_NAME
b012345,zaihan,Process
b212345,nurhanani,Check
b451234,nasirah,Call
c234567,ibrahim,Check
nike,,
USER_ID,USER_NAME
b842134,khalee,Call
h123455,shabree,Process
c234567,ibrahim,Process
c143322,zaihan,Check
b451234,nasirah,Call
"""

m = re.findall(r'(.*,,\n(.*([^,]|,[^,])\n)*)', text)

dfs = range(len(m))
keys = range(len(m))
for i, f in enumerate(m):
    lines = f[0].split('\n')
    lines[1] += ','
    keys[i] = lines[0].split(',')[0]
    dfs[i] = pd.read_csv(StringIO('\n'.join(lines[1:])))

df = pd.concat(dfs, keys=keys)
df = df.set_index(['USER_ID', 'USER_NAME'], append=True).unstack(0)

df.index = df.index.droplevel(0)
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)

df = df.stack().unstack()
```

#### Demonstration

```
print df.to_csv()

USER_ID,USER_NAME,adidas,nike
b012345,zaihan,Process,
b212345,nurhanani,Check,
b451234,nasirah,Call,Call
b842134,khalee,,Call
c143322,zaihan,,Check
c234567,ibrahim,Check,Process
h123455,shabree,,Process
```

#### Explanation

```
# regular expression to match line with a single value identified
# by having two commas at the end of the line.
# This grabs nike and adidas.
# It also grabs all lines after that until the next single valued line.
m = re.findall(r'(.*,,\n(.*([^,]|,[^,])\n)*)', text)

# place holder for list of sub dataframes
dfs = range(len(m))
# place holder for list of keys.  In this example this will be nike and adidas
keys = range(len(m))

# Loop through each regex match.  This example will only have 2.
for i, f in enumerate(m):
    # split on new line so I can grab and fix stuff
    lines = f[0].split('\n')
    # Fix that header row only has 2 columns and data has 3
    lines[1] += ','
    # Grab nike or adidas or other single value
    keys[i] = lines[0].split(',')[0]
    # Create dataframe by reading in rest of lines
    dfs[i] = pd.read_csv(StringIO('\n'.join(lines[1:])))

# Concat dataframes with appropriate keys and pivot stuff
df = pd.concat(dfs, keys=keys)
df = df.set_index(['USER_ID', 'USER_NAME'], append=True).unstack(0)

df.index = df.index.droplevel(0)
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)

df = df.stack().unstack()
```

Comment: your answer is right. Another question would be how if the headers are like `adidas,,,` and `nike,,,` (ie. with commas)? in cases i have such formatting?

I'll try to get the regex on matching anything that has empty commas `,,,` and post the results

Comment: I think i can check for any non empty commas, ie. with `b842134,khalee,Call` and based on that regex i can know it is not `nike` or `adidas`

Comment: sorry it should be `,,` and not `,,,`

Comment: I added the trailing commas.  I also adjusted the input text to show how it would work when the same user_id and name show up for both adidas and nike.

Comment: I have edited my question on some errors i had been having. I did try df.groupby(level=0) but i still have `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`

Answer (score 1):

First, `Ctrl+C` your sample data and try to run below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_clipboard(header=None)

i = np.where(~df[0].str.contains(','))[0].astype(int).tolist()+[len(df)]

frames = []
for n in range(len(i))[:-1]:
    part = df.iloc[i[n]:i[n+1]]
    part_df = part.iloc[2:, 0].str.extract('(.+),(.+),(.+)')
    part_df.columns = ['USER_ID', 'USER_NAME', '{}'.format(part.iloc[0, 0])]
    frames.append(part_df.set_index(['USER_ID', 'USER_NAME']))

final = pd.concat(frames, axis=1).fillna('')
final.to_csv('result.csv')
```

The result is,

```
USER_ID,USER_NAME,adidas,nike
b012345,zaihan,Process,
b212345,nurhanani,Check,
b451234,nasirah,Call,
b712345,ibrahim,,Process
b842134,khalee,,Call
b843432,nasirah,,Call
c143322,zaihan,,Check
c234567,ibrahim,Check,
h123455,shabree,,Process
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this helps, you could use Pandas to merge your 2 datasets.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv("csvdata.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("csvdata2.csv")

df3 = df1.merge(df2, on='USER_ID', how='left')
df3 = df3[['USER_ID', 'USER_NAME', 'NIKE', 'ADIDAS']]

print df3
```

You should change your data so it includes a heading for Nike/Adidas, get rid of all the headings in the of and write a heading with Pandas, like you have done in your original code:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("csvdata.csv", names = ['USER_ID', 'USER_NAME', 'NIKE'])
```

or

Rename you headers:

```
USER_ID,USERNAME,NIKE

b842134,khalee,Call

h123455,shabree,Process

b712345,ibrahim,Process

c143322,zaihan,Check

b843432,nasirah,Call
```

Edit:
If your data is in one file, you could try splitting it into 2 dataframes like this:

```
index = df1.index[df1['adidas'] == 'nike'].tolist()[0]
df2 = df1[index:]
df1 = df1[:index]
```

it is a little sloppy, but it should work...

Comment: There is one csv, that is the point of the question

Comment: ok, sorry I did not realise that